# Get annotate sum with calculation in django

Tags: django

I've data like below. Need to get total value by calculating `price - discount%` and sum of all. How to use aggregate here

[image: Data]

models.py

```
class Order(TimeStamp):    
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='order_item')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    discount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Please share the related model(s).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the discounted price for each item through [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

OrderItem.objects.annotate(
    total=F('price') * 0.01 * (100-F('discount'))
)['total']
```

If you want to sum up the discounted prices, we can use a [**`Sum`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum):

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

OrderItem.objects.aggregate(
    total_price=Sum(F('price') * 0.01 * (100-F('discount')))
)['total_price']
```

or for a specific order:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

myorder.order_item.aggregate(
    total_price=Sum(F('price') * 0.01 * (100-F('discount')))
)['total_price']
```

You likely want to do this *per* `Order` object:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Order.objects.annotate(
    total_price=Sum(F('order_item__price') * 0.01 * (100-F('order_item__discount')))
)
```

The `Order` objects that arise from this will have an extra attribute `.total_price` that contains the total price.

---

> **Note**: I would refrain from making a lot (all) fields `NULL`-able. It means that
> if fields are `NULL`, expressions and aggregates with these fields can be
> `NULL` as well, and often are if one of the included fields is `NULL`.
> Often `NULL`-able fields are rare, and used if it is valid to have
> *missing* information.

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the manager to fetch the related objects in reverse. Therefore
> normally the `related_name` of a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` is *plural*,
> for example `order_items` instead of <s>`order_item`</s>.

---

> **Note**: It might make more sense to work with a [**`DecimalField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField)
> than with a [**`FloatField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField)], since a decimal has fixed precision,
> and less rounding errors, Especially when working with financial data, that is more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.